# How to append data from Gmail in a new column in Google Sheets using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet where sales data is populated every day for the previous day. I want a time series view of the data by appending the data everyday at a specified time.

**Current workflow:** Data in email label is pasted into a sheet, removing the existing content.

**Required workflow:** Data in email label is pasted into a new column in the sheet and does not replace the existing content.

I'm pulling data from my email label to sheets via this code:

```js
function fsn_sales_yday() {


  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Pan India Yesterday Sales");
  var threads = label.getThreads();
  //var i = threads.length;

  //var threads = GmailApp.search('in:inbox from:"bigfoot-reporting@flipkart.com"');
  var message = threads[0].getMessages();
  message.reverse();
  var attachment = message[0].getAttachments()[0];
  attachment.setContentType('text/csv');


  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("13uCCKnY4_6F1kn54LQsrIBMTb1yeJH_FXlVN2Frd2EU");
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0]);

  // Is the attachment a CSV file
  if (attachment.getContentType() === "text/csv") {

    //var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");

    // Remember to clear the content of the sheet before importing new data
    sheet.clearContents().clearFormats();
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

    //GmailApp.moveMessageToTrash(message[0]);
  }


}
```

### How can I achieve the required result?

Comment: Hello @mark0018, would you mind sharing the code you have used and a sanitized copy of your sheet as well? That would be of great help! Cheers!

Comment: Hi @ale13, I have updated the code in the post

Comment: @mark0018 Is your csv data something that you want to have in just one column?  Can you share a sample of your csv ?